# Install Pytorch on Windows

Tags: python, conda, pytorch

I am trying to install Pytorch on Windows8.1. I am using Python 3.6.4 and no GPU. I've tried already the Anaconda package provided by `peterjc123` by running `conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch_legacy cuda80` using a virtual environment. While the installation goes smooth (without errors), after `import torch` I get the following error.

```
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 76, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can somebody help me to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing the GPU version with the command.
Check the [link](https://github.com/peterjc123/pytorch-scripts) for the github repo.

In short, you should run something like
`conda install -c peterjc123 pytorch`.
Be sure to install the required dependencies before attempting to install the main framework. For more details, check the link.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I messed up with my `conda` environments, hence I started again from scratch.